# how to send smtp mail in java 1.5?

Tags: java, email, smtp

So this is an old app, I don't have access to javax mail components. What are my options to send out email from a java app, please?

Comment: You don't have access to JavaMail, but you can make code changes to send mail? I don't get it: if you can make code changes, you can also include JavaMail to do the sending.

Comment: our client have a long check list for system upgrades, even if it is approved in the end. For now, they use 1.5 as their jvm.

Comment: JavaMail is a separate library and has nothing to with the Java Runtime. JavaMail (depending on the version) works from Java 1.3 or higher.

Comment: yes found it, thanks. It also requires Activation package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the JAR file containing the javax.mail APIs from Maven Central - http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/javax.mail/1.4.4

(Or if you are using Maven or Ivy, just add the dependency.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/15120

Answer (score 1):

If you can't (or don't want to) access javax package then only option you have to open socket connection with your SMTP server and send all the SMTP commands programmatically.

Comment: Alternatively: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smtp#SMTP_transport_example (although you won't be able to access that page tomorrow!)

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to the smtp port of the server you wish to communicate with using a java.io.URLConnection and pipe it the various smtp commands, try the example entitled "Example 5-3: The MailClient Class" here:
http://oreilly.com/catalog/javaio/chapter/ch05.html

Or there's another example here: http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/14877

Comment: the devx article is interesting in using URLConnection. What kind of dependency or configuration is required for jvm or whatever underlying system to recognize the "mailto:" scheme?

Comment: @Haoest, none that I know of...what did you end up doing in the end?

Comment: I imported javax.mail package from oracle. It has a big footprint, but I bet it's 100 times better than what I can write with raw smtp commands.